# What is the difference between using serviceAccount vs serviceAccountName in a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have seen both `serviceAccount` and `serviceAccountName` been used in a pod manifest. What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference.

`serviceAccount` is DEPRECATED and you should use `serviceAccountName` instead.

Quoting from  the [Kubernetes API docs > pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.26/#podspec-v1-core):

> serviceAccount: **Deprecated**ServiceAccount is a deprecated alias for ServiceAccountName: Deprecated: **Use serviceAccountName instead**